# Need to find Month day date from Month and year

Tags: teradata

I need to get the full date with timestamp from a column that has a format 'yyyymm'. For example i need to get 2007-01-01 00:00:00:000 from 200701.

My Column 'A' consists of:

200701
200702
200703
...
...
...

I need another to calculate another column 'B' showing:

2007-01-01 00:00:00.000
2007-02-01 00:00:00.000
2007-03-01 00:00:00.000
2007-04-01 00:00:00.000

Column B has to be a calculation based on Column A or Sys.Calendar. Using platform Teradata 14.

Please let me know the answer. Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have code that is not working which we can help you correct?

Answer (score 1):

If the datatype is a string:

```
cast(col as timestamp(3) format 'yyyymm')
```

If it's numeric:

```
cast(cast(col * 100 - 19000000 + 1 as date) as timestamp(3))
```